# How to refresh Access Token In Background thread in both Foreground And background Mode in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have a Swift 3 application with an access token that expires every 24 hours. I want to refresh then token on background thread (when the app is in either foreground or background mode) without having to bother the user, it should just happen in the background without user input.

Comment: editing for legibility

Answer (score 0):

That is not a good Idea to **refresh the token in background**...

The best way I would like to suggest you that make your **API** like it returns an **error code in response**, if you send expired token then your API will return specific response then you can refresh your token and re-call your current API with new Token.

That is natural procedure of programming rather than calling refreshing in background.

**Drawback** of refreshing in background is - If the new token has no used in next 24 hours that you have refreshed then it will make your server un-necessary calls

Comment: Thanks for response Vishal
 what i was trying to say for background that is when app is in running mode and we will get refresh access token after some interval of time